# How can i use logsumexp trick to this?

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, approximation, numerical-calculus

I m trying to compute $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^K q_k \sum_{i=1}^N \exp(- \sum_{j=1}^J P \exp(\alpha_{i,j})+ \alpha_{i,j} \hspace{1mm} cj)}{\sum_{k=1}^K q_k \sum_{i=1}^N \exp(- \sum_{j=1}^J (P-1)\exp(\alpha_{i,j})+ \alpha_{i,j} \hspace{1mm} cj )} \quad $ but the both are too small so the computer round it to $0$ and give me $\frac{0}{0}$ wich is so problematic, so i want to pass into log using logsumexp trick.

So how can i can i calculate $log( \sum_{k=1}^K q_k \sum_{i=1}^N \exp(- \sum_{j=1}^J P \exp(\alpha_{i,j})+ \alpha_{i,j} \hspace{1mm} cj) )$ ?  
 
 knowing that :

- $\sum_{k=1}^K q_k=1$
- $\alpha_{i}  $ is relied to the sum of k ( because $\alpha_{i} \sim N(0, \Sigma^{(k)}$ )
- P is a big integer
- cj is an integer for all j

logsumpexp trick is a method to calculate the log of sums
$\log \sum_{i} \exp{(\theta_i)} = \theta_* + \log \sum_{i} \exp{(\theta_i - \theta_*)}$ where $\theta_* = \max_{i} \theta_i$ 
 
thank you

Comment: If there is such a thing as the "logsumexp trick", *you* tell *us* how to use it, please!

Comment: yes the other terms are influenced by k as mentionned with $\alpha_{i}$  in the second point @LutzLehmann

Comment: the logsumexp trick allowed to us to calculate the log of sums like this $\log \sum_{i} \exp{(\theta_i)} = \theta_* + \log \sum_{i} \exp{(\theta_i - \theta_*)} $ where  $\theta_* = \max_{i} \theta_i$ @wasn'tme

Comment: According to the rules of this place, such pertinent information should be included in your question.

Comment: yes excuse me @wasn'tme